# Let $f$ be a real differenciable function such that $|f(x+h)-f(x)|\leq |h|g(h)$ with $h,x\in\mathbb{R}$ and $\lim_{h\rightarrow0} g(h)=0$.

Tags: calculus, functions

Show that $f$ is a constant function in $\mathbb{R}$.

How I did:
$\frac{f(x+h)-f(x)}{|h|}\leq g(h)\Rightarrow \lim_{h\rightarrow0} \frac{f(x+h)-f(x)}{|h|}\leq\lim_{h\rightarrow0} g(h)\Rightarrow f'(x)\leq 0$.

Question: What should I do to have $ f '(x) = 0 $?

Comment: You have forgotten a pair of |.

Comment: You should remember the absolute value sign in the question that you forgot.

Comment: I knew it was something obvious that was missing! Thanks a lot!

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Fix an $x$. What can you say about
$$\left|{f(x+h)-f(x)\over h}\right|$$
when $h\to0\>$?